# FancyBox with iframe working in Chrome but not working in IE or FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Fancybox modal window works in Chrome but doesn't work in IE or FireFox.
To view this please go to https://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net/spa1/#/invoice
Click the 'Template Styles' window.

Html:

```
<a fancybox="" href="#/templates?mp=b" class="btn fb-templates fancybox.iframe"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Template Styles</a>
```

Directive

```
myApp.directive('fancybox', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.fancybox({
                hideOnOverlayClick: false,
                hideOnContentClick: false,
                enableEscapeButton: false,
                showNavArrows: false,
                scrolling: false,
                iframe: {'scrolling': 'no'},
                onComplete: function () {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $compile($("#fancybox-content"))($scope);
                        $scope.$apply();
                        $.fancybox.resize();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this only happens in a Single Page Application. My final workaround was to add another html page and reference it when calling pop windows:

```
<a fancybox="" href="popup.html#/templates?mp=b" class="btn fb-templates fancybox.iframe"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Template Styles</a>
```